# how to get value of last text box, that dynamically created

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, children

This code dynamically creates some text boxes.
How to get value of 'last' text box in this UniformGrid?
Web search did not make a good result!

Many thanks

```
       public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
            for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                uniformGrid.Children.Add(new TextBox
                {
                    Width = 70,
                    Background = Brushes.Beige,
                    HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                    Height = 30,                        
                    Margin = new Thickness(3)
                });
            }            
        }
```

Text boxes contains dates,I want to get last text box value and display in new text box with button event.

```
private void datePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime a = DateTime.Parse(datePicker.Text);
            foreach (Control c in uniformGrid.Children)
            {
                TextBox textbox = c as TextBox;
                if (textbox != null)
                {
                    textbox.Text = a.ToString();
                    a = a.AddDays(1);
                }                
            }
        }


private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
lasttextBox =...
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with more details. Where do you want to access the last text box? From another class or a click event or just below within the constructor? What have you tried so far?

Comment: To elaborate, what exactly defines the "last" TextBox for you? Is it the furthest to the bottom right, is it the one with the newest date, or is it something else entirely.

Comment: 'last' is final (bottom right) text box in uniformGrid. Suppose we have dates1 to 30 and want to get the date of 30 and display in new text box.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to enumerate with the foreach the way you're doing it. You can simply say foreach (TextBox t in uniformGrid.Children) { ... } It'll implicitly skip any other controls of a different type. Also, you can use the SelectedDate property of the DatePicker instead of parsing the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `TextBox` is going to be the last one you add and therefore the highest index value in the `Children` collection.

```
int lastIndex = uniformGrid.Children.Count - 1;
var lastBox = (TextBox)uniformGrid.Children[lastIndex];

ResultTextBox.Text = lastBox.Text;
```

In the event that you have other controls in there then you simply need to enumerate on only the text boxes *(you could even save the result since you're doing the enumeration in the* `SelectedDateChanged` *event handler).*

```
TextBox lastBox = BoxGrid.Children.OfType<TextBox>().Last();
ResultBox.Text = lastBox.Text;
```